# IF < = 0 then 0 with a CASE statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server....

I am starting with a fixed value then subtracting specific hours types. I end up with some negative and some positive numbers. So far so good but what I need is if the value is <=0 then I want to set the value to 0 but just can't get the syntax quite right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
... ,36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') THEN OTH_HRS ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity'

110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 09/04/2018  2018-09-02  5.6
110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 09/11/2018  2018-09-09  -4
110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 09/18/2018  2018-09-16  -3.25
110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 09/25/2018  2018-09-23  3.5
110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 10/02/2018  2018-09-30  13.38
110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 10/09/2018  2018-10-07  3.75
110019000   7A Antepartum   Unit Technician 10/16/2018  2018-10-14  -0.5
```

Full SQL:

```
SELECT 

       ID [EmployeeID]
      ,DEPTNAME [Department]
      ,JOBTITLE [Job]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EARNS_END_DT,101) [Apply Date]  
      ,DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EARNS_END_DT) , CAST(EARNS_END_DT -1 AS DATE)) AS 'Week Start' -- Adjust the "-2" to set the proper DOW 
      ,36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') THEN OTH_HRS ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity'
      ,36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') THEN IIF(OTH_HRS <=0, 0, OTH_HRS) ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity'
      ,36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') AND OTH_HRS >= 0 THEN OTH_HRS ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity' 

    FROM    
        PAYROLL_DATA D  
        INNER JOIN  PAYCODEMAP P ON P.PAYCODENAME = D.DESCR 

    WHERE EARNS_END_DT BETWEEN '8/28/2018' AND '8/26/2019'

    GROUP BY

       ID
      ,DEPTNAME
      ,JOBTITLE
      ,EARNS_END_DT

    ORDER BY 
        EMPLOYEEID 
        ,[Week Start]
```

Comment: You need to specify the RDBMS you are using. For example in SQL Server you use `IIF(value <=0, 0,value)`, in other systems, the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use `IIF` with `CASE`

```
SELECT ... ,36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') THEN IIF(OTH_HRS<=0, 0,OTH_HRS) ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity'
```

OR

this one
Use `AND` in 1 `CASE` statement

```
SELECT ... ,36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') AND OTH_HRS >= 0 THEN OTH_HRS ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity'
```

This is an example of how to use it, in all cases no negative values have been returned.

Make sure the `36-SUM` part is the right thing to do

```
 DECLARE @Temp as table (PAYCODECATEGORYFK varchar(3), OTH_HRS int)

 INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES
('REG', 3),
('REG', -4),
('REG', 0),
('PTO', 8),
('PTO', -2),
('PTO', 0),
('AAA', 9),
('BBB', -1),
('CCC', 0)

SELECT  CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') THEN IIF(OTH_HRS<=0, 0,OTH_HRS) ELSE 0 END   AS 'Unused Capacity' 
 FROM @Temp P

SELECT 36. - SUM(CASE WHEN P.PAYCODECATEGORYFK IN ('REG', 'ABU', 'PTO', 'LEAVE', 'HOL') THEN IIF(OTH_HRS<=0, 0,OTH_HRS) ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Unused Capacity' 
 FROM @Temp P
```

Comment: It tried both of these, the first one seems like it is ignoring the  <=0 part and just returning the same value. The second one is behaiving the same way. I have to admitt, I'm scratching my head on this.  110001000 Neuroscience Acute Care Unit Unit Manager III 08/13/2019 2019-08-11 -4 -4 -4

Comment: I just added the full SQL in my question above. It was too long for the comment.

Comment: @Doug I modified the answer.

Comment: @Doug Try the query first without Grouping, once you make sure you get the right results from the CASE statement then do grouping